# Javascript: Different return types

Tags: javascript

I saw I could return different types from the same function in JavaScript. Is this practice idiomatic or should it be discouraged?

For example:

```
somefn = function(e) {
    switch (e.type) 
    {
       case 'mousedown':
         return false;
       case 'mousemove':
         return {x:10, y:20};
    }
 };
```

Comment: 2 close votes, and two up vote for the qn :-) .. I mentioned I am new to the language, and all other languages I know won't allow it..

Comment: It is idiomatic, in the sense that it's "not forbidden", as the "function" object has neither input or output type enforcement, leaving it to the programmer to decide. The "return" statement may return any kind of object, including functions, or even nothing. That could be useful in some cases, like returning a string if there is a match, or false if not (if a zero length string would be a valid match, for example), or returning a number if there is an answer, or null if not (X/Y, for example, it could return null if Y is zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that not only your function returns different types, but might even not return anything:

```
somefn({type: 'foo'});  //undefined
```

Although inconsistent return behavior described above is discouraged, returning different object *types* is common, although I can't say if it is idiomatic.

For the sake of readability and maintainability I wouldn't recommend returning completely different objects (like boolean and object literal in your example), but returning object literals with just slightly or even completely different properties is pretty common:

```
somefn = function(e) {

  switch (e.type) 
  {
    case 'mousedown':
      return {x:10, y:20, down: false};
    case 'mousemove':
      return {x:10, y:20};
    default:
      return {};
  }
};
```

Comment: that's strange, i would prefer to return `null` rather than create an empty object. and if i had to choose between `{}` and `false` i would go with `false` since at least i could do an easy `if(returnValue)` which would be more complicated in your code... that would actually be the best place to return a *different* object (like `false`, but better `null`), because i can check general success by the return value's boolean value, and use it as an object if that check passes.

Comment: Agree, but with empty object literal you can safely do things like: `if(somefn(e).down)`. Guess it's a matter of taste :-). BTW I would really like the `if({})` to return `false` in JavaScript...

Answer (score 7):

I would discourage it. Any code that uses a function that can return different types depending on the context will have to check the returned value.

There are situations where it makes sense, however. Say you have a function that parses a string, for example JSON. In that situation it makes a whole lot of sense to return arrays if the input string is a JSON string representing an array, an object if the input contains an object, a boolean, a number, etc.

In general, do the thing that would cause the least surprise. Your example would surprise me a lot, for example.

Answer (score 4):

it is very common that one function return different types of object in javascript, just write it, invoke it and determine the type of return value.