# is it bad for the function to return values of different type

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I  wonder if its considered a  bad prcatice to  return values of different type for the function. Consider the code:

```
function getInterval() {
 var interval = getIntervalValueFromLocalStorage();
 if (interval < 0) {
  return false;
 }
 return interval;
}
```

So whenever I  need the  interval  that function  returns I  can write

```
var interval = getInterval();
if (interval) {
 //do some staff
}
```

In this case:

```
function getInterval() {
    return  getIntervalFromLocalStorage();
}
```

I  will have to  check if the interval is less than 0 and it doesn't seem  very  neat

Comment: It is as ugly as working with *null*.
Is there any possibility to work with sane defaults?

Comment: kindly check following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849256/javascript-different-return-types

Comment: You could just change your if statement. `if(typeof getIntervalFromLocalStorage() === "number")` would only trigger for numbers and would negate the need for `getInterval` altogether

Comment: Your example is flawed though, because when interval is 0, the condition in `if (interval)` evaluates to false anyway

Comment: @Gio, good notice, but  I'm  interested about  the case with negative numbers

Comment: @Olena, i prefer to use same type of data for standard programming. So that one who calls the function never wants to expect multiple type of data . Yes you can pass -ve number in your example code a negative return .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear objective answer to this but here is my take on it.

There are essentially two considerations here: performance and readability/maintainability.

For performance always taking the same argument types and returning the same types can have a big impact (for example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/). In practice these differences are often ignorable unless you need fast code.

With regards to maintainability consistent return values do also help (in my opinion). The one exception I make is returning null which is what I would do in your case.

I'd recommend avoiding even those if reasonably possible. For instance a getCurrentUser() function could return a AnonymousUser instance rather than null when no user is logged in. This avoids a lot of null checks and the bugs associated with forgetting them.

**So in short: Avoid returning different types whenever reasonably possible.**

Answer (score 2):

> Is it bad practise to return values of different types from a function?

Yes, it certainly is. While necessary in some cases, it makes semantic reasoning about your code harder, which is important for maintainability and correctness. And it also makes it harder for the compiler to optimise.

In your specific case, you should rather return `0` instead of `false` when the interval id is not valid.